# Moment of a Force violates conservation of energy?

Tags: forces, energy-conservation, torque

Moments of a force is defined as $M = F.d,\; \text{where d = perpendicular distance}$

Let's suppose a screw requires $5\:Nm$ and with a spanner of $1\:m$, Force of $2.5\:N$ is insufficient.

But if we double the length of spanner, we can increase the turning force and move the screw.

Where's this extra energy to turn the screw with a longer spanner coming from? Surely, from energy's point-of-view increasing distance shouldn't add any energy - potential or otherwise (if you imagine spanner is parallel to the ground, being pushed down; $P.E$ remains the same)

The proof that extra energy is being applied is by that fact the screw now *moves* with the long spanner. This means more 'energy' spent turning the screw to allow it to overcome its resistance - but where is this extra energy coming from?

Comment: If you  mean 'torque' when you write 'turning foce' then your statement is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The energy comes from the body of the person wielding the spanner. If you double the length of the spanner, you also double the distance through which the spanner has to be turned, which doubles the work.